# How can I display only the top three rows in a report?

Tags: t-sql, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have 2 fields in a report: `job#` and `hours worked`. I have it grouped by `job#` and then a sum on the hrs worked. I would like to be able to have just the top 3 `job#` with the most hours in the sum. can this be done?

Comment: Are you asking how to do this in TSQL, or in Crystal Reports? If it's TSQL then look at [`TOP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in group sort expert it lets you filter by top n